# Задача на С++ олимпиадная

Tags: c++, алгоритм, математика, олимпиада

> Вокруг ведущего стоит N человек, которые пронумерованы по часовой стрелку числами от 1 до N. Ведущий, начиная с первого отсчитывает M человек и тот, на котором остановится счет, выходит из круга. Счет возобновляется со следующего человека, и так до тех пор, пока не останется один. Определить номер последнего человека.

Подскажите, в каком направлении идти?

Comment: Какие конкретно ограничения на N и M?

Comment: Иди в напралении модульной арифметики. (имхо)

Comment: @Harry каких-то конкретных ограничений нету, но думаю в пределах пары десятков будет достаточно

Comment: Берите  последовательность  булевского типа такой же длины,  считайте по кругу, каждый раз устанавливая значение M - того элемента true, и не считайте такие... На последнем остановитесь

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ну, для нескольких десятков можно просто смоделировать :) - с помощью простейшего массива, например...
O(N<sup>2</sup>) вполне достаточно для таких чисел.

Для более серьезных N можно воспользоваться рекурсивным O(N) решением

```
int J(int n, int m)
{
    if (n == 1) return 1;
    return (J(n-1,m)+m-1)%n+1;
}

int main()
{
    int n, m;
    cin >> n >> m;
    cout << J(n,m) << endl;
}
```

Понятно, что его легко превратить в итеративное:

```
int J(int n, int m)
{
    int j = 1;
    for(int k = 1; k < n; ++k)
    {
        j = (j+m-1)%(k+1)+1;
    }
    return j;
}
```

Миллионные числа сработают быстро, миллиарды будут тормозить...

А вообще - ищите *"Задачу Иосифа Флавия"*.

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно. Идея с массивом была, но понимал что это костыльный способ и можно решить лучше :)