# Задача Иосифа с++ с помощью циклического связного списка проблема со связью во 2 очереди

Tags: c++

Проблема возникает во 2 очереди.  К примеру войнов 10, интервал 2 и после 9 война идет 1(что неправильно)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
 
struct Node
{
    int m_item;
    Node *m_next;
    Node(int item, Node *next) { m_item = item, m_next = next; }
};
 
int main()
{
    cout << "Voin: "; //интервал удаления
    int NumberOfElements = 0;
    cin >> NumberOfElements; // ввод кол-ва людей
    cout << "M: "; // ко-во людей в списке
    int interval;
    cin >> interval; // ввод интервала
    Node *first = new Node(1, 0);
    first->m_next = first;
    Node *tmp = first;
    cout << "Deleted elements:" << endl;
    for (int i = 2; i <= NumberOfElements; ++i)
    {
        tmp->m_next = new Node(i, first);
        tmp = tmp->m_next;
    }
    while (tmp != tmp->m_next)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < interval; ++i)
        {
            tmp = tmp->m_next;
        }
        Node *deleteNode = tmp->m_next;
        tmp->m_next = tmp->m_next->m_next;
 
        cout << tmp->m_item << endl;
        delete deleteNode;
    }
    cout << "Last warrior:" << tmp->m_item << endl;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

подскажите, пожалуйста

Comment: да я сам не прав. нужно посмотреть нормально гайд, а не спрашивать тут. подскажите в чем проблема, ведь элементы удаляются в неправильно порядке

Comment: Посмотрите здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/963594/195342 Или список — требование, которое нельзя обойти?

Comment: @Harry, да нужно сделать односвязный циклический список

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы печатаете номер не того узла который удаляете. Нужно так:

```
<   cout << tmp->m_item << endl;
------
>   cout << deleteNode->m_item << endl;
```

Вы сперва пропускаете узлы, затем удаляете один узел. Порядок должен быть обратным: удалили, пропустили.

После этих двух правок задача решается правильно.

**P.S.** Не удержусь и покажу как задача решается на списка в стиле [Джона Кармака](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA,_%D0%94%D0%B6%D0%BE%D0%BD). Ему приписывается идея работать не с указателями на узлы, а с указателями на указатели на узлы. Это даёт возможность удалять не следующий узел (как это делается обычно) а текущий:

```
#include <iostream>

struct node_t {
    int i;
    node_t *next;
    node_t(int i) : i(i), next(nullptr) {}
};

int main() {
    int n, m;
    if (!(std::cin >> n >> m)) {
        return 1;
    }

    node_t *head = nullptr;
    node_t **tail = &head;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        *tail = new node_t(i + 1);
        tail = &(*tail)->next;
    }
    *tail = head;

    node_t **p = tail;
    while ((*p)->next != *p) {
        std::cout << "remove " << (*p)->i << '\n';
        *p = (*p)->next;
        for (int j = 1; j < m; ++j) {
            p = &(*p)->next;
        }
    }
    
    std::cout << "last " << (*p)->i << '\n';
}
```

**P.P.S.** В этом коде узлы не удаляются, просто вырезаются из списка.

Comment: у вас нумерация узлов с 0 же начинается?

Comment: Нет, `new node_t(i + 1)`.

Comment: спасибо, да. увидел и проверил. все работает. как раз мне и нужен был односвязный циклический список. очень помогли